# working with placeholder in variable names in Python, wx.python

Tags: python, variables, wxpython, placeholder

I am working with wxpython and want to shorten my qode by working with loops. The following example is not working and I am wondering how to get it work.

```
Keys = ['Q_geo_ges_h','Q_geo_ges_k']
Values = [12.6,1.943]
for key,value in Keys,Values:
    'self.%s'%key = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,value=str(value))
```

Is there any way to assign a variable from a list of strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to make a sequence of `key`, `value` pairs.

```
>>> keys = ['Q_geo_ges_h', 'Q_geo_ges_k']
>>> values = [12.6, 1.943]
>>> zip(keys, values)
[('Q_geo_ges_h', 12.6), ('Q_geo_ges_k', 1.943)]
```

And use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) to set attribute:

```
keys = ['Q_geo_ges_h', 'Q_geo_ges_k']
values = [12.6, 1.943]
for key, value in zip(keys, values):
    setattr(self, key, wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, value=str(value))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exacty what I needed - I can use that a lot.

Comment: @zoipi note that in most cases it's simpler and cleaner to use a dictionary for cases like this instead of using `setattr` - for starters, it keeps the data separate from all other attributes of your object. And falsetru, this is a very common XY problem in python, you shouldn't go around recommending `setattr` to an obvious beginner without at least mentioning dictionaries.